# How to handle dynamic JSON value types when deserializing request with Spring?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I'm trying to create a wrapper for a piece of software our company is using to interface with their API using Spring.

Right now, this software's API returns a flat JSON object as the response of a `GET` request. The problem that I'm facing is depending on whether or not there is data in one of the fields we are grabbing from will determine whether the value in the response is either a String or a JSON object.

How does one handle this dynamic data type when creating a model in Spring?

When just playing around with the data, if the data is empty for this specific field and I have the data type set to `String` in my model, I'm able to deserialize this to my `result` object.

Vice versa for when there is data for this specific field. I create a custom object called LinkValueObject which just contains 2 attributes `link` and `value`. When I make the request when there is data for this field, once again I'm able to deserialize this properly. I'm just not sure how to handle either case dynamically.

My apologies if I got the terminology wrong.

Example of response w/ no data in "assigned_to":

```
{
    "result": {
        "name": "Bob Ross",
        "assigned_to": ""
    }
}
```

Example of response w/ data in "assigned_to":

```
{
    "result": {
        "name": "Bob Ross",
        "assigned_to": {
            "link": "https://mylink.com",
            "value": "qwerty123456"
        }
    }
}
```

My model right now looks like this:

```java
// Using Lombok to auto-generate getters/setters

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude("JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL")
public class Result {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    // This will handle if assigned_to returned as a JSON object
    // If assigned_to was empty, it would return as an empty string
    // and cause this to bomb out until the Data type was String again

    @JsonProperty("assigned_to")
    private LinkValueObject assignedTo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Declarative Stream Mapping (DSM)](https://mfatihercik.github.io/dsm) stream parsing library to easily do this.

First of all, you must define the mapping between JSON data and your fields in yaml or JSON format.

Here are the mapping definitions:

```
result:     
   type: object
   path: /result   
   fields:
     name: 
     assignedTo:
       type: object
       path: assigned_to
       filter: self.data.link!=null  # if link value is null filter assignedTo field                        fields:
          link:
          value:
```

Java class that you want to deserialize(Same as your classes):

```
public class Result {
    public String name;
    public LinkValueObject  assignedTo;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Result [name=" + name + ", assignedTo=" + assignedTo + "]";
    }
    public static class LinkValueObject{
        public String link;
        public String value;
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "LinkValueObject [link=" + link + ", value=" + value + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

Java Code to parse JSON:

```
DSM dsm=new DSMBuilder(new File("path/to/mapping.yaml")).create(Result.class);
Result  result=  (Result)dsm.toObject(jsonData);
```

System.out.println(object);

Here is outputs:

First Input:

```
{
    "result": {
        "name": "Bob Ross",
        "assigned_to": ""
    }
}
```

First Output:

```
Result [name=Bob Ross, assignedTo=null]
```

Second Input:

```
{
    "result": {
        "name": "Bob Ross",
        "assigned_to": {
            "link": "https://mylink.com",
            "value": "qwerty123456"
        }
    }
}
```

Second output:

```
Result [name=Bob Ross, assignedTo=LinkValueObject [link=https://mylink.com, value=qwerty123456]]
```